# Can somebody tell me what I need to do to have selenium autoclick these radio buttons?

Tags: python, selenium

update: Something about shadow root? Looking deeper into it now.

Retyping the entire question because I was in a hurry the first time I wrote it up, apologies.

I'm writing a program to automate refreshing the Disney Park Reservation page and click "Theme Park Tickets" then "July 20", then have it check for a "checkmark" image next to "Disney's Hollywood Studios". If the checkmark isn't there, the program continues to loop until it is found. If the checkmark is there, it will automatically compose an email and send it to me so that I can go ahead and make a reservation.

MY CURRENT PROBLEM

I can't figure out what XPATH or ID or Name to use in my code for "Theme Park Tickets" as well as "July 20". Nothing has worked, and I've tried a lot. I would give you a list of specifics but I'm a little to busy to do so, my apologies.

WHAT I NEED

I'd love to know what I need to put in my code in order for selenium to autoclick both buttons. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the link to the webpage I'm looking at.
https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/availability-calendar/?segments=tickets,resort,passholder&defaultSegment=tickets

def main():

```
while True:

    options = Options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/availability-calendar/?segments=tickets,resort,passholder&defaultSegment=resort')
    driver.maximize_window()
    sleep(7)
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html/body/app-root/div/app-availability-selector/awakening-selector//dprd-radio-group/dprd-button[1]")
    ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(button).perform()
    sleep(5)
```

main()

[HTML for the Theme Park Tickets button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfbdw.jpg)

[HTML for the July 20 button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc2uv.jpg)

[One of the errors I've been getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMqBI.jpg)

Comment: Your code and html source?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Retyped the entire question. Sorry about that!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, put them into the question as text in code blocks.

Comment: Fixed again. Sorry guys, I'm new to this.